# Get Input Data Value in Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get the value of this input.

```
<input type="text" name="txtEmployeeNo" value='{{ $employee->employee_no }}'>
```

Its value is `53210`. How can I get that in my controller?

I currently have this on my controller.

```
$employeeNum = $request->input('txtEmployeeNo');

$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employeeNum])->get();

return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',compact(,'employeeSched'));
```

The problem is when I open and see if it is fetched nothing is showing. I cannot get the input.

Comment: In the controller definition you need to typehint the parameter to be passed to it like this: `public function pageController(Request $request){` then you can access the input value like you have tried: `$request->input('txtEmployeeNo');`

Comment: @user3647971 hello, i already did that but still nothing is being fetched

Comment: Is your input element inside a form that you submit?

Comment: Show us your blade :)

Comment: @user3647971 no not in a form

Comment: @user3647971 this is a form inside the text input `     {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

Comment: @Mozammil heyy sir, i think that is the only important part of my blade file nothing else.

Comment: Are you using which version of laravel? I don't see the documentation for that kind of form handling under version 5

Comment: @user3647971 laravel 5. sir

Comment: In laravel 5 I use this syntax for forms: `<form action="{{route('named.route')}}" method="POST">@csrf // this is important
<input name="asd"/>
 </form>`

Comment: We need to see more. Your full controller method and the blade file (at least the part where the form is concerned)

Comment: @Mozammil can we chat sir please? i dont know how can we chat hre ill show you the whole blade file there

Comment: @obitouchiha have you tried `$request->get()`? I suggested this because recently I failed to properly understand the difference between `input()` and `get()` of Request class.

Comment: `public function pageController(Request $request){}`
change to 
`public function pageController($id){
/* here is your value */}`

Comment: @KiranKanzar then that will do nothing, because how can i call the input if it has no `request` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$employeeNum = $request->input('txtEmployeeNo');

$employeeSched = Schedule::where('employee_no', $employeeNum)->get();
return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',compact('employeeSched'));
```

well, here is an edit to this answer with the steps needed:

1. in your routes:

   Route::post('yourRouteName','yourController@nameOfFunctionInController')->name('TheNameOfTheRoute');
2. In your controller:

   public function nameOfFunction(Request $request) {

   ```
   $employeeNum = $request->input('txtEmployeeNo');

   $employeeSched = Schedule::where('employee_no', $employeeNum)->get();
   ```

   return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',compact('employeeSched'));

   }

And that's it basically.

Comment: If you do `dd($request);` in the top of the function inside the controller, what do you get? @obitouchiha

Comment: it says `null` when i put it on the very top of my controller public function

Comment: I will edit my answer, so you can see the steps that you need to do.

Comment: i will sir. ill wait fr it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should must work.

```
$employeeNum = (isset($request['txtEmployeeNo'])) ? $request['txtEmployeeNo'] : 0;
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employeeNum])->get();
return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',$employeeSched);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller insert this line after opening your function:

```
dd($request->all);
```

It will show you everything that has been posted through your form with values. If you get your 'txtEmployeeNo' without value, it means something went wrong when you insterted it in your `input`.

**Check with dev tools if that specific input has any value.**

If your input has the value you mentioned and your `$request->all()` still shows an empty value for your "txtEmployeeNo", then the error is in the HTML/Blade file.

- Make sure you create the form correctly
- Make sure your input's name equals with the request you are trying to receive in your controller.

If you get `null` as the value of the `$request`, that could mean, in your Blade file, the input also has it's value as `null`.

**Try to manually insert a value like `<input type="text" name="txtEmployeeNo" value="2">` and see if you get that in your controller. If you do, then the query in your input is wrong.**

That's all I could think of without provided Blade and Controller code.

Comment: here it is `null` it says null only

Comment: so when you DD your posted form, your have something like this?
"txtEmployeeNo" => null?

Comment: I guess, null means your input has that value in your blade file mate. check the input's value, try to manually write something in it and check your DD after that

Comment: hello sir all iwant is to get the value of the textbox but it seems nothing is being get on the value. i want to get `54232` but i cannot get its value :(

Comment: Mate, please try the steps I suggested... Check if the input has any value please

Comment: @obitouchiha did you check the input's value in your blade file? does it have 54232?

Comment: @Patrick Alexits, hey sir im still getting the `null` when i put the line inside my public function :(